# Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma - Lighting Profiles per Game on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hardware, audio-hardware

I just got my Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma Headset today, and is my first of the kind, so have no idea.

Just after opening Razer Synapse, I am taken to a "Lighting" page where I can change the lights on the sides of my Headset to either:

**- Static** Stays on a single colour of my choice.
**- Breathing** Stays on a single colour of my choice fading in and out, simulating breathing.
**- Spectrum** Displays all displayable colours in the visible spectrum.
**- Off** Obviously turns the lights off.

After little use, I'm already loving the hell out of this headset, but am wondering:

**Am I able to make it so when I open a game, it changes to a Static Pink, Static Orange for another, Spectrum when neither, etc.?**

After googling for results, I was able to find the [Razer Chroma Configurator](http://www.razerzone.com/chroma-configurator), but looks like it's used for Keyboards. This is the closest I got to what I was looking for.

**PS: I am on a Macintosh, so any Windows programs will likely not work, although I'm willing to Wine it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By scanning through Razer's website, and search engines, there is absolutely no information given which shows any evidence towards a program that does such a thing, thus it essentially doesn't exist.

With Razer keyboards such as the [**BlackWidow Chroma**](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-keyboards-keypads/razer-blackwidow-chroma), profiling is available, but not for the [**Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma**](http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-audio/razer-kraken-71-chroma).

Comment: LOL that was quick but probably correct... Same answer as I came across.

Answer (score 1):

After searching, I have found the Chroma App called "ChromaSync".  You can find this App from the [Chroma Workshop](http://www.razerzone.com/chroma-workshop#chroma-apps).  Only issue I see with this is it only has support for `Counter Strike: Global Offensive` as of this moment, but the creator is still working on this app.  The app is also only in Version 1.0.

This app is Windows only though, and I am running Mac OSX so I cannot test this app.

Comment: I haven't mentioned, which I probably should have, that I am also on a Mac, and therefore have no use for a Windows program... It sucks, but it looks like we're on out own....

Comment: @nil oh, by what I have found you cannot have profiles for Razer Kraken.  I will edit and undelete my other answer I posted earlier explaining what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through the Razer Synapse many times and I have found nothing.

As you can see below the Razer Naga Epic Chroma has an option for "Profiles" and "Link Application".
[image: Razer Synapse settings 1]

While Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma does not.
[image]